# Run Function for Every Div Class Individually

Tags: javascript

My goal is is to insert the current day's hours for each business `<div class="business">`, since this is becoming a more common feature of business listing sites to include "Today's Hours."

So far, I'm able to show the hours for the first business div based on the current day. However, I'm unable to repeat the function for each `<div class="business">`. The IDs within each business div are specific to that business, but I realize there are multiple of the same IDs throughout the HTML.

I'm trying to isolate the code to run specifically for each `<div class="business">` but it continues to only work on the first instance. I've read about .each() and so on, but nothing that seems to work for my particular situation.

---

### **Here is my test HTML:**

```
<div class="business">
  <h3> Business One </h3>
  <p id="dayZero">Sunday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="dayOne">Monday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="dayTwo">Tuesday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="dayThree">Wednesday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="dayFour">Thursday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="dayFive">Friday Hours 1</p>
  <p id="daySix">Saturday Hours 1</p>
  <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span id="currHours"></span></p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="business">
  <h3> Business Two </h3>
  <p id="dayZero">Sunday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="dayOne">Monday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="dayTwo">Tuesday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="dayThree">Wednesday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="dayFour">Thursday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="dayFive">Friday Hours 2</p>
  <p id="daySix">Saturday Hours 2</p>
  <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span id="currHours"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
getCurrHours();
</script>
```

---

### **Here is my JavaScript:**

```
function getCurrHours() {

  var dayZero = document.getElementById("dayZero").innerHTML;
  var dayOne = document.getElementById("dayOne").innerHTML;
  var dayTwo = document.getElementById("dayTwo").innerHTML;
  var dayThree = document.getElementById("dayThree").innerHTML;
  var dayFour = document.getElementById("dayFour").innerHTML;
  var dayFive = document.getElementById("dayFive").innerHTML;
  var daySix = document.getElementById("daySix").innerHTML;

  var currDay = getCurrDay();

  function getCurrDay() {
  switch (new Date().getDay()) {
      case 0:
          day = "Sunday";
          break;
      case 1:
          day = "Monday";
          break;
      case 2:
          day = "Tuesday";
          break;
      case 3:
          day = "Wednesday";
          break;
      case 4:
          day = "Thursday";
          break;
      case 5:
          day = "Friday";
          break;
      case 6:
          day = "Saturday";
      }
  return day;
  }

  var currHours = compareDays();

  function compareDays() {
    switch ( currDay ) {
      case "Sunday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayZero;
          break;
      case "Monday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayOne;
          break;
      case "Tuesday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayTwo;
          break;
      case "Wednesday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayThree;
          break;
      case "Thursday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayFour;
          break;
      case "Friday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = dayFive;
          break;
      case "Saturday":
          hours = document.getElementById("currHours").innerHTML = daySix;
      }
  return currHours;
  }

}
```

---

### **Here is the JSFiddle: [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jschaffranek/qp3ahLue/)**

Comment: You have tagged jquery but you're not using it. You really want a jquery solution?

Comment: IDs *have to* be unique across a html document.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I've seen similar cases suggesting .each(), so I'm not sure if there is a jquery solution or not. I'm open to whatever will work, pure javascript or jquery.

Comment: @Christoph should each ID be a class then? Would that edit work for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs always have to be unique in an HTML document, otherwise you get a lot of unpredictable behaviour when trying to select elements.

Change it to structure like below. By eliminating the duplicate `id`s and looping over the business elements, it is straight forward to use a simple `forEach` to fetch all the needed business hours.

```js
var currDay = (new Date).getDay();
var businesses = document.querySelectorAll(".business");

businesses.forEach(function(business){
  // use a regular string concatenation if you need better browser compatibility
  var currHours = business.querySelector(`p[data-day='${currDay}']`);
  var currHoursDisplay = business.querySelector(".currHours");
  currHoursDisplay.innerHTML = currHours.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div class="business">
<h3>
Business One
</h3>
<p data-day="0">Sunday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="1">Monday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="2">Tuesday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="3">Wednesday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="4">Thursday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="5">Friday Hours 1</p>
<p data-day="6">Saturday Hours 1</p>
<p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span class="currHours"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="business">
<h3>
Business One
</h3>
<p data-day="0">Sunday Hours 2</p>
<p data-day="1">Monday Hours 3</p>
<p data-day="2">Tuesday Hours 2</p>
<p data-day="3">Wednesday Hours 2</p>
<p data-day="4">Thursday Hours 4</p>
<p data-day="5">Friday Hours 3</p>
<p data-day="6">Saturday Hours 2</p>
<p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span class="currHours"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! I appreciate it! I spent so much time on this. It didn't even occur to me to use data. I'll keep this in mind going forward. And definitely about the multiple IDs. Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome!;-) If my or one of the other answers helped you solve your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This indicates to the SO community, that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/qp3ahLue/10/

It finds each business with `querySelectorAll` and runs your code for each `<div class="business">`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.business').forEach(function(business) {
    getCurrHours(business);
});


function getCurrHours(business) {

    var dayZero = business.querySelector("#dayZero").innerHTML;
    var dayOne = business.querySelector("#dayOne").innerHTML;
    var dayTwo = business.querySelector("#dayTwo").innerHTML;
    var dayThree = business.querySelector("#dayThree").innerHTML;
    var dayFour = business.querySelector("#dayFour").innerHTML;
    var dayFive = business.querySelector("#dayFive").innerHTML;
    var daySix = business.querySelector("#daySix").innerHTML;

    var currHours = business.querySelector("#currHours");

    switch (getCurrDay()) {
        case "Sunday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayZero;
            break;
        case "Monday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayOne;
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayTwo;
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayThree;
            break;
        case "Thursday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayFour;
            break;
        case "Friday":
            currHours.innerHTML = dayFive;
            break;
        case "Saturday":
            currHours.innerHTML = daySix;
    }
}


function getCurrDay() {
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0:
            day = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            day = "Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            day = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            day = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            day = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            day = "Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            day = "Saturday";
    }
    return day;
}
```

```html
<div class="business">
    <h3>Business One</h3>
    <p id="dayZero">Sunday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="dayOne">Monday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="dayTwo">Tuesday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="dayThree">Wednesday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="dayFour">Thursday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="dayFive">Friday Hours 1</p>
    <p id="daySix">Saturday Hours 1</p>
    <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span id="currHours"></span></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="business">
    <h3>Business Two</h3>
    <p id="dayZero">Sunday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="dayOne">Monday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="dayTwo">Tuesday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="dayThree">Wednesday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="dayFour">Thursday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="dayFive">Friday Hours 2</p>
    <p id="daySix">Saturday Hours 2</p>
    <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span id="currHours"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code here. Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of great answers out here, but here's how using jQuery. I would greatly encourage learning the learning the language!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var day = new Date().getDay();

  $(".business").each(function() {
    $(".currHours", this).html($(".day-" + day, this).html());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="business">
  <h3>Business One</h3>
  <p class="day-0">Sunday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-1">Monday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-2">Tuesday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-3">Wednesday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-4">Thursday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-5">Friday Hours 1</p>
  <p class="day-6">Saturday Hours 1</p>
  <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span class="currHours"></span></p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="business">
  <h3>Business Two</h3>
  <p class="day-0">Sunday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-1">Monday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-2">Tuesday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-3">Wednesday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-4">Thursday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-5">Friday Hours 2</p>
  <p class="day-6">Saturday Hours 2</p>
  <p style="color:red">Today's Hours: <span class="currHours"></span></p>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/qp3ahLue/12/)

Comment: JQuery *is* Javascript, so technically it's not a new language. Also imo it's losing lots of relevance because js heavily improved over the last couple of years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm a novice to both JS and jQuery, but I'm working on learning both.